# Converting a list to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a list in Python that I would like to convert into a dictionary. The list is:

```
l = [('1:', [362.5815, 162.5823]), ('2:', [154.1328, 354.133]), ('3:', [168.9325, 368.9331]), ('4:', [9.9201, 209.9206]), ('5:', [106.4842, 306.4844])]
```

The dict should have the integers 1,2,3,4,5 as keys and the lists as values. I have tried using

```
def Convert(l):
    it = iter(l)
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
    return res_dct
```

and

```
def Convert(l):
    res_dct = {l[i]: l[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)}
    return res_dct
```

But these don´t work due to list being an unhashable type.
How else could I convert this list? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second example is almost right. But you don't want `l[i]` as the key because that is a tuple. Instead you want `l[i][0]`, the first element of the tuple, as the key.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I don't think so. Even if poster does `l[i][0]`, its the string with the colon, not an integer, and it skips every other list item.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, changing `l[i]` to `l[i][0]` and `l[i + 1]` to `l[i][1]` is only the first step towards the solution. This change would solve the immediate error that list is not hashable. My point is that the OP is heading in the right direction to get there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - But its not the right direction. One shouldn't use range + indexing when a simple iteration will do the job. The first exmaple is closer to right than the second.

Comment: @tdelaney Just because `range()` isn't pythonic doesn't mean using it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @tdelaney As I spell out in my answer below, there is a clear step-by-step process to take the second example and transform it into a working solution. I'm not sure how I would transform the first example into one. That doesn't mean there isn't a way. It's just less obvious to me because it is more complex.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - The first example is close, `res_dct = dict(l)` would hands down be the best answer if not for the issue that you need to transform the key. You could do `dict((int(k.strip(":")) ,v) for k,v in l)` (or use the dictionary comprehension) to fix it. The second attempt is inferior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Convert(l):
    res_dct = {l[i]: l[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)}
    return res_dct
```

This is almost right. The problem is that `l[i]` is an entire tuple as the key. Instead, you want the first element of that tuple: `l[i][0]`. Similarly, the value needs to be `l[i][1]` to get the second element of each tuple. With this in mind, there is no reason to skip every other element in the list. Putting it all together:

```
def Convert(l):
    res_dct = {l[i][0]: l[i][1] for i in range(len(l))}
    return res_dct
```

A more pythonic way is to iterate over the elements of the list directly rather than using indexes on the list:

```
def Convert(l):
    res_dct = {i[0]: i[1] for i in l}
    return res_dct
```

And you can use some more python syntax to get rid of indexing the tuple, too:

```
def Convert(l):
    res_dct = {k: v for k, v in l}
    return res_dct
```

But the `dict()` class already does this with a list of pairs, so we can simplify this even more:

```
def Convert(l):
    res_dct = dict(l)
    return res_dct
```

All of these three variations will turn the list of tuples into a dictionary. However, they will use the elements exactly as they are. In particular, the key  will be a string with digits and then a colon. If you want to modify they keys to be integers, then you can't use the final version that calls `dict()`. Instead we will use the dictionary comprehension and apply some functions to the key:

```
def Convert(l):
    res_dct = {int(k.strip(':')): v for k, v in l}
    return res_dct
```

After all that, I would consider just making a list of lists. When keys are in sequential order, a list makes more sense than a dictionary:

```
def Convert(l):
    res = [v for k, v in l]
    return res
```

The keys are taken care of by the list for you. This assumes that the original elements are already in order.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. The version returning the keys as integers is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

```py
d = dict()   
for (k, v) in l:
    d[k.strip(':')] = v
```

Be aware of repeating keys in your list, as only the last list will be kept, if you expect duplicate keys you need to decide on a strategy to handle them differently (e.g. merge them or keep the first assignment instead of the last assignment as implemented here)

EDIT
On below comment off dict comprehension and int conversion for keys, this could also be done (not so sure on legibility though)

```py
{int(key.strip(':')):value for (key,value) in l}
```

Comment: And I think you need to add an `int(..)` in thete, otherwise they are just strings.

Comment: You can reduce this to a single line with a dict comprehension.

Comment: Good answer, but you could add the alternate `d = {int(v[0].strip(":")):v[1] for v in l}` as a dictionary comprehension which I think would be a typical python solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and enumerate

```
{i: v[1] for i,v in enumerate(l, 1)}
```

Comment: This assumes that the integers are always 1, 2, 3, ... It would fail if the data was anything other than this. I think you've assumed too much here.

Comment: @tdelaney - Potentially but the op also says "The dict should have the integers 1,2,3,4,5 as keys and the lists as values" so the current first elements of the tuples could just as easily be misleading

Comment: But that's just because the example had "1:", etc... We don't know whether this is the rule or just this one example. Its more a questoin to OP than an answer until we know.

Comment: Using `enumerate()` assumes that the input list is already in the correct order. It is safer to use the first element of each tuple to get the key instead.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I'd agree if thats what the OP's intention was, I interpreted slightly different such as the ops original list was sorted and they were potentially converting it into a dictionary of "ranks" i.e 1st 2nd 3rd, as opposed to the value used for sorting (based on the "should have the integers 1,2,3,4,5 ")